# SqlDatareader Has Rows with Multiple Result Sets

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a result sets in which there are 3 results. The first result set has no rows and next result sets has rows. How to check if each result sets has rows?

When i tried this it is saying false

```
reader.HasRows //this returns false

reader.NextResult() 

reader.HasRows //this agains returns false but this result has rows
```

Comment: Not really sure why you are having this issue, but can't you use `DataSet` and fill it up with DataAdapter ?

Comment: @Habib,Thanks, but i really need to use `SqlDataReader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to execute your query directly from SQL to see what is the result you get.
Maybe you could try to re-think the original query and insert there a check for empty result set.

[Here is a sample](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-multiple-resultsets.htm) of DataReader with multiple result sets: do you see something different from the code you're using?

Comment: pls read first line of my question. I already executed in sql and i told that first result set has no rows and the next 2 result sets has rows.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you've already execute in SQL. At this point, I can only suggest you to try the following code, just to check how many result sets you're getting from your code, to be shure that you don't get any "empty & unexpected" set that you don't see in SQL:  `do
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // if you came here, the current set has rows
        }
    }
} while (reader.NextResult());`